# The colors that we see

Tags: coordination-compounds, color

I have a question. When I was studying *Coordination Compounds*, I came across this para:

> When a sample absorbs light, what we see is the sum of remaining colors that strikes our eyes. Observed and absorbed colors are generally complimentary.

Now, I have doubt that does sample word applies to all the objects of universe? I mean if we are, for example, painting an object orange, does it mean that we are actually painting blue and we are seeing it's complimentary color Orange?

Please clear my doubt on this.

Comment: @Arnav I suggest you take a look at how perception of color works for some "enlightenment". While I don't see anything wrong with the question, it seems off-topic to me for Chem.SE and better suited for Physics.SE.

Comment: Yeah or maybe just suggest a link where one can read about it and have it done with?

Comment: Yes to your final question. The point is that following your line I should have answered NO.

Comment: The OP is commendably curious, but this question is off-topic.

Comment: Thanks @user79161. I will post this at physics SE. Actually, I read about this in Chem, that's why.

Comment: These questions are fundamental, the best answered rather by searching than by querying/answering, as the former provides more complete and detailed answer. There are tons of information on internet  or in textbooks about this topic.

Comment: The question seems to be perfectly on topic in a Chemistry site. Now reading the entire thread it seems that a full answer is more time consuming that at a first glance. OP you should have fixed it now if you read my first ironic comment. What you say in the question is true. However color rendering can be achieved in different ways. For instance a red LED is not a red paint. In this case it is the LED itself that emits red, opposite to common case in which we see the light impinging an object minus the components that the latter has absorbed/diffused in other random directions.

Comment: See [Additive color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_color) and [Subtractive color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtractive_color)

Comment: Complimentary colors are very polite, but complementary colors are the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

**Your problem is a much linguistic as chemical or physical**

When you say you paint something "orange" you describe the visible colour you see as a result of applying the paint. It makes no sense to describe the "colour" of the paint as anything else.

The physical process involved in making the paint that colour is, indeed, absorbing the colour ranges complementary to orange. But it makes no sense to describe the paint as anti-orange. Unless you are colour scientist who needs to clarify how the object would look under illumination with a different mix of wavelengths. In which case you probably won't be unclear about the relevant terminology or processes.

Comment: That is (at least as formulated in the question) the point. Plus 1. It is also true that from just this point of view the question is off topic both here as well as in Physics SE.

Comment: In bold, it should be "as much linguistic as..."

Comment: @user79161 it should be *than* rather than *as* or *a*.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you illuminate with white light a blue object. At an atomic scale what is happening is the following:

Photons of all the visible spectrum frequencies are striking the object, and many of these are being absorbed by the object. This causes the electrons of the atoms to being excited and promote to higher energy levels. This state of the electrons are unstable so they decay with time generally to the ground state. In this way down, there are some "paths", some jumps between levels, that are very likely to occur which are characteristic of the particular atom. In our example, the atoms of the object must have a characteristic jump that emits photons in the frequency of blue.

To physically see an object, the object must absorb the light and then re emit it in a particular frequency to you. Glass for example do not absorb light (the photons do not get absorbed by its atoms), so they pass by and never come back to us. The glass therefore is transparent. A red object absorb light and then only re emits red photons,

Comment: Something like at the botton happens in part but it is not why we see a red object to be red. The first paragraph is totally wrong as it would imply absorbing red photons and emitting blu ones.

Comment: @Alchimista of course that a body can absorb red photons and emit blue ones. If for example a red object could absorb only red photons, it would be transparent for all the colors, which would travel throug it without being absorbed. Obviously this is not the case and maybe you are confused with the case, for example, of a pure sodium gas that when illuminated with white light, basically only absorbs a characteristic yellow and all the remaining photons would cross the gas. This is not what happens in a red opaque object.

Comment: "Of course... blue ones". This is blatantly wrong. Your answer implied up-conversion. True is that the colour in transmission can be even different than that seen by reflection. In short, it is not even true that "must absorb the light and then re emit". I am surprised by the number of down vote. The answer is totally wrong.

Comment: @Alchimista the electrons in the atoms do not "reflect" light in the classical sense, they absorb photons or do not interact with them, as they are bound to the nucleus, they cannot change their energy any way they want (obviously this is a simplification, but we are dealing here with the major effect). As you will disagree with this, please, explain how an atom "reflects" a photon (I mean, name the process).

Comment: do at least realise your sentences to be wrong? If you are after the microscopic quantum level mechanism of reflection, this is not what OP were asking for. Beware that it is right taking an atom (an atom does not reflect light by definition) that confuses you and/or your answer. There is nothing concerning atomic orbitals in reflection, including transition among them. Reflection is a properties you might even have at the interface of two both transparent clear materials. Finally beware that even a sample of gas, in which collective wavefunction aren't present, won't behave as you claim

Comment: In brief, a red opaque object visible only if illuminated is red because it absorbs blu, not because it emits red. More clear that this.... Case exist in which high energy photon results on fluorescence of course, but at least agree that we are leaving the OP trace. As far the question is of relevance, the answer is given above by Matt_Black. I am here just because I thought that your answer will let OP with the idea of knowing more, but that more is wrong.

Comment: @Alchimista I do not want to confront with you, I'm just trying to explain myself because I really think you point is wrong.

Comment: A red object for sure have spectral lines that lie in the red part of the spectrum. How couldn't it absorb and emit that frequency of light? if that object absorbs all the rest of the colours, what happens to the excited electrons? don't they emit light when they decay? I think that you must explain this very well for maintaining your position.

Comment: If you would like to read a good explanation of this absorption and re-emission process, see the answer from Selene Routley: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137293/what-happens-to-photons-after-they-hit-objects of course I'm not inventing the wheel here.

Comment: Well I couldn't say that is particularly good. But at least I see that semantic can play a role in our diatribe. OK, let us call *absorber* everithing which is in reality *interacting*. In such a case every step of a photon-matter interaction can be called *absorption*. The point is that while this is clear in the answer you link, it is not clear in your answer. In other words, your answer suggest that reflection happens for photons that can be absorbed by the object, The level that you mention in the blu example are simply not there. Your mistake arises by seeing everything as a isolated atom

Comment: "A red object for sure have spectral lines that lie in the red part of the spectrum. How couldn't it absorb and emit that frequency of light? if that object absorbs all the rest of the colours, what happens to the excited electrons? don't they emit light when they decay? I think that you must explain this very well for maintaining your position".This is the source of your misunderstanding other answers. No, it is not true. An object that reflect blue does not need those levels, unless you bring in the discussion some virtual state or something really unstable. They will be at the surface in...

Comment: .. in case of perfect mirror. In no case that light propagate within the bulk, right because the material cannot absorb it. Your way of thinking basically negate reflection.

Comment: @Alchimista you can talk about reflection in a classical way: Snell's law, Frensel's equations, and so on. This approach, absolutely valid for a lot a issues, starts to fail if you dig into its nature, once you enter the quantum world. So I think when you try to understand how light interact with matter, you must talk about QM (I'm not trying to be "exquisite"). Here what we call classical reflection is the process of absorbing one type of photons and re-emitting exactly the same.

Comment: The metals are shiny because their "free" electrons can absorb and then re-emit practically all the frequencies (electronic band structure). If a metal could not absorb the photons, it would not be a mirror as you say, it would be transparent (the photons would never came back to your eye). That happens in glass, which is transparent for visible light but opaque for UV light (this photons have the adequate energy to excite the glass structure, thus, being absorbed).

Comment: Matter can absorb one colour and emit other. https://www.fnal.gov/pub/science/inquiring/questions/colorofatoms.html from Fermilab "In molecules, where two or more atoms share some of their electrons, the molecules can absorb light of one color and emit another color. This works whether the atoms are the same (eg two Nitrogen atoms) or different elements. Paints and dyes (the chemicals used to color clothes) are complicated molecules where the arrangement of the electrons make the molecules reflect specific colors very well."

Comment: From the same link, about reflection of light: " The part of an atom or molecule that "reflects" the light is the electrons on the outside of the atom. Now..the color comes in two steps..
Step 1: The electrons first absorb some of the light that hits the atom or molecule.
Step 2: The electrons which absorbed the light then emit (give out) some light "

Comment: You can put it as you wish. There must be an interaction,that is sure. The point is that your simple picture absorption - emission either negate reflection, as for tell me why the emission does not happen forwards in the bulk..., or negare bulk absorption. The absorber you refer to are quantum object at the surface. In such a sense a body that has them does not absorb. Your treatment mixes mirror with gases and it is messed up. I am perfectly fine with absorber on the surface of a mirror. The mirror doesn't not absorb.

Comment: Then it can be a linguistic friction between us. This does not make your question a better one, though we may substantially agree that an interaction of the type absorption/re-emission can take place at the external boundary of metals/mirrors. But if you take that photons can be absorbed/re-emitted at frequency where the absorbance is zero, that is wrong. We won't be able to record zero absorption! Which in turn invalidate the opening of your question. A red object does not absorb light and then re emit red photons. A red object absorbs blue photons, at least in this simple context.

Comment: @Alchimista little more I can say. For understanding this issue of colors you must use the quantum picture: photons are being absorbed and then re-emited for us to see the object, there is no other possible way. Assuming only the classical picture of reflecting EM wave lead to the well known errors one can read at the start of any quantum physics textbook. In this picture the classical reflection consist in the absorption of photons that excite electrons in the atoms, which then emit the same photons as they decay.

Comment: The classical absorption appears when an asborbed photon creates phonons in the material so the T raises, etc... (the zero absorbance you measure in a metal or a mirror, has nothing to do with the absorption and reemision of light, as you measure neat absorption when the light is finally not reemited, for example in a black body). But this is not what we are talking about, we are focus in the colors we see.

Comment: I don't understand very well why don't you accept that it is possible to absorb blue photons and reemit red ones as it is the same process that happens in fluorescence (the only difference is that the frequency of the photons are higher). The contribution to the final reflected ray will depend on the material, but this is certainly something that will happen, how couldn't be?

Comment: Under absorption, I consider what is really is absorbed. The absorption re-emission interaction you refer to dies not take place within the level you mention in your answer. The state you are referring to are either extremely short living, perhaps as much to be virtual ones, or are so called surface plasmon. Surface right because not the body nor its atoms or molecule can net absorb at that frequency. Again, it might be that the only difference between our two pictures is, as already have been the case with the question, a merely linguistic conflict. In the sense that you call absorption...

Comment: ... what I call interaction. And absorbers what I call oscillators. Your mechanism is anyway messed up or mixing up different thing. Pure scattering (by emission or by Rayleigh type mechanisms) let us already see things. That is why we see spectral lines. Spectral lines *of atoms* are indeed lines which are  absorbed and emitted. But we see tham as lack of light! You omit that fluorescence is diffusive. You omit that generally the transitiond upwards predominate over those downwards, because of population of the levels. This said, of course we see what somehow arrives at our eyes.

Comment: "I don't understand very well why don't you accept that it is possible to absorb blue photons and reemit red ones as it is the same process that happens in fluorescence (the only difference is that the frequency of the photons are higher). The contribution to the final reflected ray will depend on the material, but this is certainly something that will happen, how couldn't be?" It does happen. But this is *fluorescence*, which is not the only way a body is visible to us, and is even a relatively rare phenomenon in solids.

Comment: I love when in a interchange, the discussion finally gets distilled and more directed to the exact point of conflict. The process of absorption re-emission is not marginal, is THE process that it is actually going on for we could see. More precisely, it is the process that accounts for the classical reflection. You can get prove of this studying any spectrum of any atom. For example: if you illuminate  sodium gas with white light, and then you analize the colours of the beam after passing the gas, it seems the yellow line is missing,

Comment: but what really happens is that the sodium atoms are absorbing this colour and then re-emiting it in every direction, so the intensity you get in the direction of the white beam is greatly diminished. This has nothing to do with plasmons or virtual states. Please, if you have a reliable source that state this is a minor process, let me know. I can say by the way that thing like Raman or Rayleigh scattering indeed are minor in the matter we are talking about: "Rayleigh scattering usually has an intensity in the range 0.1% to 0.01% relative to that of a radiation source.

Comment: An even smaller fraction of the scattered photons (approximately 1 in 10 million) can be scattered inelastically, with the scattered photons having an energy different (usually lower) from those of the incident photons—these are Raman scattered photons" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raman_scattering. In regular objects it is very imprecise to say: "absorbs everything, and reflects red". Even in pure atoms their spectrum have peak with a little width. Regular object emit (reflect) a lot of colors and all that enormous combinations is what we call red.

Comment: They might have the most prominent peak around the red wavelengths, but certainly if you decompose their light you will see a rainbow with more intensity in the red part of the spectrum, etc... You will almost never get monochromatic colours with regular objects.This things that I'm talking about are the things I remember from my years at university studying a physics degree (quantum physics courses, particle physics, etc...) and the things I study now for my work as a science high school teacher. If you can point out with data a real mistake it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Fich, all the above is certainly correct. The point is that if we see a gas, we see it by mean of its diffusion (proper scattering processes, like Rayleigh etc... , fluorescence, eventually phosphorescence) and not by absorption. But sn atomic gas is virtually invisible, except if you analyse the spectrum as you said. But atoms. You might well discuss the reflection as well as scattering in terms of abs/re-em from an oscillator. What is different is that the excited state created by the "abs" does not decay *with time* through "some paths*. No, it does not extend within the body because is

Comment: the corresponding state does not exist in the object. Again, is not really clear to me if all this has just a linguistic ground or is genuine. I might continue when I'll have time (if they don't stop us :))

Comment: @Alchimista there was indeed linguistic matter as at principle I did not get what did you mean by absorption (my net absorption). But anyway I think that we have reached a point that either one of us is right and the other wrong. I stated that a blue photon could eventually be reemited as red colour, you say this is wrong because the corresponding state does not exist in the body. This is not true because the spectrum of an ordinary object has a lot, plenty of lines.

Comment: I know this is this way for sure, but truth be told I never saw data not did any experiment to know the degree of importance of the effect (absorbing blue light and then reemiting red). If the effect is marginal, has little importance if it happens or not (for our discussion, as conceptually I think is important, marginal or not).

Comment: Finally I found a video that can settle down our discussion: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJhuf0Um-Eo  See 0:50, he uses UV light, and then blue light to make orange, yellow and green liquids get their colours. This not happen when illuminated with red light as the photons have less energy. He gives an interesting data too in 7:44: "fluorescence is common among organic molecules". Why do you said that fluorescent is rare? (I do not know).

Comment: Re-reading the discussion I see I made the mistake of saying that an object can absorb red photons and emit blue ones. This is false as the red photons never can excite the atoms so much to re-emit blue ones (if an electron absorbs rapidly various photons of lower energy, it can reach states that could decay emitting higher frequencies, but this has to have a negligible probability). Evidently, you can only absorb in one frequency and then emit in the same or lower ones, not higher.

Comment: yes that is a point that is surely wrong but I did not put much weight on it. Though is related, as there won't be way to see a blue object when illuminating it with a blue lamp. Obviously isn't the case (contrast trouble omitted).

Comment: (Written before our last two comments above). I am not saying that a blue photon can't be absorbed than re-emitted as red. This is fluorescence, of course! But a body can be blue without fluorescence, and this is by far the most common case. Otherwise we would need UV lamp to light a room. The blue of the above body would be due to reflection and/or scattering. If you model the processes...

Comment: .... If you model the processes you..... might see them as absorption followed by re-emission, the point is that the emitted light is not that that leading to absorption / fluorescence in atom nor the one that would be emitted at the end of a decay process in molecules and solids.

Comment: No no, if a body has the transition to absorb the blue light, a great deal of it will be remitting transitioning down the same way (this is the classical reflection). But a significant part of this blue photons will produce other colours as well. In this video you can see how as you illuminate the bottom sea with blue light will produce an intense blue light being reflected (absorbed and then re-emitted in the same spectrum band-line).

Comment: But if you use a filter to filter the blue light, you will see all the colours. This is impossible to understand without the absorption re-emission process. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E56IuJumLAE This is purpose of my original answer: if an object appears yellow, the yellow we see is not only coming from the yellow that is being reflected (absorbed and then re-emited), there are contributions from other photons with higher energies that are decaying in such a way that eventually produce yellow photons as well.

Comment: I gave up. There is no way for water to absorb in the visible (except for overtones of the OH vibration giving, in long optical path, its blue-greenish hue. All the rest are reflected photons. Free to call them absorbed-re-emitted but they basically do not deposit energy into the body (except for vibrations, they can indeed move from surface into depth and warm the body). Another point it seems missed in your reasoning is that in molecules and even more bodies there are plenty of non radiative channels to relax. This is actually well known by all those aiming at fluorescent molecules...

Comment: ..., which is already a task, able to retain fluorescence in solid state. You mixed up so many phenomena that I can't even answer if not by disparate points. Even in scattering, no the sky isn't blue because because UV transforms into blu. Blue is scattered. Calling absorber an oscillator, while can be adequate and correct in a context, can also cause both semantic as well as physical confusion.

Comment: ok @Alchimista. I'm gald we had the interchange. It served me to clarify some points (I even emailed an old university professor of mine to ask a few questions :)). Maybe we will have an encounter in another question haha bye!

Comment: one point is sure. I am not much into optics but I do agree that something can be called abs-reemit to justify interaction. This can solve the linguistic issue that was almost certainly present at beginning. Moreover I spotted this because of the supposed energy up conversion that was buried in your answer/comment. Other phenomena are relevant in context, surely we do not see object by Raman. Nor using laser as illumination source. Actually we should restart the discussion from scratch, possibly without thinking of atoms because we do not see them.